# Problems inserting image from directory

Tags: c#, image

I am having some problems inserting a image i have in my directory. I search through the resources I have on the internet and manage the relevant code to be use.

`pictureArray[]` > is a field

Created using this code:

```
using System;  
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    class Field
    {

        public PictureBox picbox; 

        public Field()
        {
            picbox = null;
        }

    }
}
```

At the top of the code, i initalize it:

```
private Field[] pictureArray = new Field[100];
```

The portion of my code as following:

```
pictureArray[0].picbox = new PictureBox();
pictureArray[0].picbox.Image = System.Drawing.Image.FromFile(@"..\Postlogger\test.jpg");
pictureArray[0].picbox.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(17, 19);
pictureArray[0].picbox.Name = "picBox";
pictureArray[0].picbox.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(50, 50);
this.groupBox1.Controls.Add(pictureArray[0].picbox);
```

My image doesn't appear on my screen. Any suggestion to what i have done wrongly? 
Thanks!

Comment: what happens when you do `pictureArray[0].picbox.Visible = true;` ?

Comment: @Yahia nope image didn't appear. and there's no error message either.

Comment: ok then try `this.groubBox1.Invalidate(); this.groubBox1.Update();`

Comment: what tyoe is `pictureArray` ?

Comment: hey. not sure what you meany by type. I edited the questions with more details on how i created the pictureArray field

Comment: are you using a second thread ?

Comment: sorry. what is a thread?

Comment: I have tried to do the same thing and your code works fine. You should try to add a normal picturebox instead of using your array. Maybe you can find out what's wrong :)

Comment: then the answer is no (thread)... so that leaves us with some problem with the `Location` and/or `Size`... you should change them and/or not set them at all and see what happens... also: what is the Size/Position of `groupBox1` ?

Comment: this.groupBox1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(12, 17); this.groupBox1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(229, 522);

Comment: now that becomes weird... what are trying to achieve ?

Comment: am trying to achieve this: laying images over another image. i have a image in groupbox1 say image1. and i wish to insert multiple image (image2,3,4...) over image1

Comment: then that is the wrong way... perhaps someone else can give you working code for this...

Comment: so you try to create some effect with image manipulation ? I suggest you using another way.

Comment: not really image manipulation. my background image > image 1 is a map. then i have images of different units. am trying to map the image of the units onto the map based on coordinates in a text file. any suggestion how i can go about it?

Comment: If you look at carefully your code is throwing exception. Try wrapping your code in a try-catch and you will see the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can see problem in your code :)

You have declared array of reference type

```
private Field[] pictureArray = new Field[100];
```

If you try and debug you will see all elements in `pictureArray` are `null`. On the next line you are doing

```
pictureArray[0].picbox = new PictureBox();
```

I believe it is throwing exception here as `pictureArray[0]` is `null`. Please instantiate `Field` object before referring it.

```
pictureArray[0] = new Field();

pictureArray[0].picbox = new PictureBox();
```

This should work now.

Comment: nope. the new picture box didn't appear. is it because, i am trying to put 2 picture box on top of each other?

Comment: What do you mean by new Picture box did not appear? are you instantiating Field elements using new Field() before referring it?

Comment: I quickly tried the code posted by you and It was not working for me because the statement pictureArray[0] = new Field(); was missing. I suggest you add it before you are doing pictureArray[0].picbox = new PictureBox();

Comment: yup. i inserted pictureArray[0] = new Field(); but it didn't work. is ok, i think i found another way to achieve what i want. thanks!